# MySQL Decimal not returning results

Tags: php, mysql

**Table:**

```
mysql> describe tbl_affiliate_commissions;
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(255)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sale_minimum      | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sale_maximum      | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commission_amount | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Values:**

```
mysql> select * from tbl_affiliate_commissions;
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| id | sale_minimum | sale_maximum | commission_amount |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
|  1 |         0.00 |        99.99 |              5.00 |
|  2 |       100.00 |       249.99 |             10.00 |
|  3 |       250.00 |       499.99 |             20.00 |
|  4 |       500.00 |       749.99 |             35.00 |
|  5 |       750.00 |       999.99 |             50.00 |
|  6 |      1000.00 |      1999.99 |             75.00 |
|  7 |      2000.00 |      3999.99 |            100.00 |
|  8 |      4000.00 |     10000.00 |            300.00 |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_affiliate_commissions` 
WHERE sale_minimum >= '359.80' 
AND sale_maximum <= '359.80'
```

Running this query returns zero results. If you run either "WHERE" statement without the other, a result is returned. Why is this happening?

Comment: Think about the logic here. You are telling the query to look for a record in the table that has a sale_minimum of 359.80 or greater AND a sale_maximum of 359.80 or less. There is no record that fits that description. What exact information are you looking for here? We can only guess your intentions otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional expressions are backwards.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_affiliate_commissions` 
WHERE sale_minimum <= 359.80 AND sale_maximum >= 359.80;
```

Or, try `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_affiliate_commissions` 
WHERE 359.80 BETWEEN sale_minimum AND sale_maximum;
```

Comment: Also, the single quote should be removed since not a string literal though implicit conversion may happen.